# Early congestion detection

Tags: linux-networking

Is there any tool in Linux which will help me to detect network congestion in advance ?

If it is able to tell me that a particular network is congested, how can I route my
packets through a different route to avoid the congested network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mtr combined with traceroute is what you are looking for.

Comment: Using mtr I am able to detect the congested network but how can I skip that congested network and route my packets through other available network?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't detect congestion in advance of it happening; that'd involve an Ethernet-enabled crystal ball.  What you want is a fairly difficult thing to do, actually, and I only know of the Avaya/RouteScience devices that deal with this in any meaningful way, by monitoring your links and upstreams and them manipulating your BGP routing table and announcements to route around congestion.  They're not cheap, though.  Internap FCP is a hosted product that I'm led to believe does a similar thing.